# EOT's, FF's, Z's, ?'s, and other fancy characters at the end of written *.txt file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

By complete accident I've noticed few minutes ago, that for some unknown for me reason, Java's `BufferedWriter` ends its work with numbers (e.g `int`) in `*.txt` files by changing the last value in that file to `EOT`, `FF`, `Z`, `?`, or even `{` (for number `1234`). The problem disappears, when I change numbers into `String` before start writing them into `*.txt` file. What is going on? I couldn't find any good explanation for this case, so I'll appreciate all explanations.

Here is a sample code, which is helpful, in demonstrating the issue mentioned above:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Zzz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BufferedWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("zzz.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (i != 9) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        if (j != 4) writer.write(j + "\t");
                        else  writer.write(j + "\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        if (j != 4) writer.write(j + "\t");
                        else  writer.write(j);
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the issue itself:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BufferedWriter#write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-) takes the `int` but writes a `char`.

What happens in `writer.write(j + "\t");` is that `j + "\t"` automatically is converted into a `String`, specifically, taking the current value of `j` and appending a `"\t"'` in the end. Similar for `writer.write(j + "\n")`. But `writer.write(j)` will take `j` as `int` and will use int value of `j` as a `char`. You can check a specific behavior if doing this:

```
int x = 90;
System.out.println((char)x);
```

Output:

```
Z
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. So basically, when I use `BufferedWriter.writer(int i)` Java translates `i` into `Unicode` character representation, in this case `88` for `X` or, like you said, `90` for `Z`. Other symbols, like `EOT`, `FF`, `?`, were shown, because `char` is a 16bit type and it scope is from `0` to `65 535`.

Comment: Another note is that you should close the writer after the try-catch.  The buffer will not call close if an exception is thrown.